# How to sort and print array listing of specific file type in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a loop with which I want to extract text file names in all sub-directories and append certain strings to it. Additionally, I want the text file name sorted for numbers after `^`.

For example, I have three sub directories `mydir1, mydir2, mydir3`. I have,
in mydir1,

```
file223^1.txt
file221^2.txt
file666^3.txt
```

in mydir2,

```
file111^1.txt
file4^2.txt
```

In mydir3,

```
file1^4.txt
file5^5.txt
```

The expected result `final.csv`:

```
STRINGmydir1file223^1
STRINGmydir1file221^2
STRINGmydir1file666^3
STRINGmydir2file111^1
STRINGmydir2file4^2
STRINGmydir3file1^4
STRINGmydir3file5^5
```

This is the code I tried:

```
for dir in my*/; do
  array=(${dir}/*.txt)
    IFS=$'\n' RGBASE=($(sort <<<"${array[@]}"));
    for RG in ${RGBASE[@]}; do
    RGTAG=$(basename ${RG/.txt//})
    echo "STRING${dir}${RGTAG}" >> final.csv
done
done
```

Can someone please explain what is wrong with my code? Also, there could be other better ways to do this, but I want to use the for-loop.

The output with this code:

```
$ cat final.csv
STRINGdir1file666^3.txt
STRINGdir2file4^2.txt
STRINGdir3file5^5.txt
```

Comment: Usually it is more convenient to use `find` and a `while` loop. To fill an array bash has the `mapfile` command, which is together with `find` more reliable.

Comment: to your code: the line starting "IFS" is not do what you expect. remove the `IFS=$'\n'` or replace the line with `mapfile -t RGBASE < <(sort <<<"${array[@]}")` to print all lines. But the sort is still not working.

Comment: To correct the sort, use this line `RGBASE=($( printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | sort -t"^" -k2 ))`. This tells `sort` to sort the number after the hat.

Answer (score 4):

As a starting point which works for your special case, I got a two liner for this.

```
mapfile -t array < <( find my* -name "*.txt" -printf "STRING^^%H^^%f\n" | cut -d"." -f1 | LANG=C sort -t"^" -k3,3 -k6 )
printf "%s\n" "${array[@]//^^/}"
```

To restrict the directory depth, you can add `-maxdepth` with the number of subdirs to search. The `find` command can also use regex in the search, which is applied to the whole path, which can be used to work on a more complex directory-tree.

The difficulty was the sort on two positions and the delimiter.
My idea was to add a delimiter, which easily can be removed afterwards.
The `sort` command can only handle one delimiter, therefore I had to use the double hat as delimiter which can be removed without removing the single hat in the filename.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using decorate-sort-undecorate idiom could be:

```
printf "%s\n" my*/*.txt |
sed -E 's_(.*)/(.*)\^([0-9]+).*_\1\t\3\tSTRING\1\2^\3_' |
sort -t$'\t' -k1,1 -k2,2n |
cut -f3
```

assuming filenames don't contain tab or newline characters.

---

A basic explanation: The `printf` prints each pathname on a separate line. The `sed` converts the pathname `dir/file^number.txt` into `dir`**\t**`number`**\t**`STRINGdirfile^number` (`\t` represents a tab character). The aim is to use the tab character as a field separator in the `sort` command. The `sort` sorts the lines by the first (lexicographically) and second fields (numerically). The `cut` discards the first and second fields; the remaining field is what we want.

Comment: This is a very effective technique, but you may want to explain to the OP that you are temporarily adding tabs to the existing filenames with `sed` in order to simplify and improve the sorting with `sort` using the tabs a field separators. I suspect much of that was lost on the questioner.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Fair enough. Added a basic explanation.